# Matching rows in two excel documents

Tags: excel

I am dealing with two large csv files in excel (around 100-400 MB each), one of which needs to be split into two documents (D1 and D2) in order for me to open it. Call the other one D3. Each row in these documents aside from the header is of form ID, Data1, Data2, Data3... Data 10 or so, with documents D1/2 havin different data than D3.  I want to add the information from documents D1 and D2 into D3, but only for the IDs that are present in D3 (a smaller file). What is the easiest way for me to do this? I also still have the D1/2 file if I can do it without opening the file in excel.

Sorry if this was a confusing question, I can answer clarification questions if needed

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I followed the rules, read through that sectoin and I believe my question is fairly straightforward. Is there any part you find confusing?

Comment: You read it but did you comprehend it?? Please try again.

Comment: There is no need to be so pretentious, if you are confused about part of my question just say it.

Comment: lol. Just goes to prove that reading != comprehension. Good day.

Comment: A much better approach would be to import the csvs into a db engine (e.g. sql server express or mysql or whatever fits best your skills & needs) and execute an update query against D3 (then export the way you want to use the data). Excel is not a very good db tool and large files might cause issues, as well as the max. row count is (quoting from MS) "1,048,576" (EDIT)On top of that it was not designed for large scale "data manipulation" (might result in stability loss along with slow processing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have something here that will get you started, please have a look and let me know about the logic of your data merge.....

```
Sub MergeData()

Dim D1 As Worksheet
Dim D3 As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Arr1 As Variant
Dim Arr2 As Variant
Dim Rw1 As Long, Rw2 As Long


'IF you the master file and 1 of the other files first in excel
'you can just reference them like this, otherwise change this accordingly
Set D1 = Workbooks("CSV1").Sheet1
Set D3 = Workbooks("CSV3").Sheet1


'D3 is the masterFile
'Lets store its data in Arr1
Set Rng = D3.UsedRange
Arr1 = Rng.Value

'since your working on large files lets try keep memory usage down to a minimum
'we will work on 2 sheets at a time not all 3.
'Arr2 now contains the sheet (CSV1) we will extract data from
Set Rng = D1.UsedRange
Set Arr2 = Rng.Value

Set Rng = Nothing

'Notice the + 1, its to skip the headers in case your wandering
'This is the basic loop setup
For Rw1 = LBound(Arr1, 1) + 1 To UBound(Arr1, 1)
    For Rw2 = LBound(Arr2, 1) + 1 To UBound(Arr2, 1)
        If Arr(Rw1, 1) = Arr2(Rw2, 1) Then  'OR  lcase(Arr(Rw1, 1)) = lcase(Arr2(Rw2, 1)) if letter case might be a problem
            'we found a matching ID
            'now im not sure exactly what you want to happen here.....
            'do you want to check if the master file has all the data that the other file has
            'if not then transfer the columns of data it is missing
            'or should all the columns in the master file be updated with the new values in the other file.....
            'This will change what code needs writing here
            'we may need an aditional array to hold new values temporarily
        End If
    Next Rw2
Next Rw1

'After all data has been extracted
'this code will also depend on what happens above
'but something like this
'set rng = D1.Range("this will be the size of the array").Value = Arr1
```

End Sub

the exact same code will be used for the second file so i only did the 2 files to start.

we need more input regarding what data to extract and if we are replacing anything in the master file etc etc, be specific.